# Einstein's photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photoelectric-effect

Why does the photocurrent remain same even after increasing the frequency in photoelectric effect? What I think is since the kinetic energy of electrons increases, the photocurrent should also increases.

Answer (score 1):

When we increases the frequency of light. It increases the kinetic energy of electrons. But since the intensity is constant the number of electrons ejected will always be same.so, the electrons will reach the receiver plate in a fixed value even though they are moving rapidly

Answer (score 1):

Well, the current is essentially just the amount of electrons that are being excited when you point the light at the material. This does not depend on the frequency of the light but rather on how many photons hit the material. And the "amount of photons" is another way of talking about "intensity".